# displaying images using java applet 10 cards shuffler Having errors :(

Tags: java, image, compiler-errors, applet, awt

I am supposed to   use an applet to display images of playing cards. The applet should load a deck of 52 playing card images from the "images" folder that you downloaded. The applet should shuffle the deck (use a random number generator) and display the first 10 cards of the shuffled deck. Display the cards in two rows of five cards each.
and when I run my program it shows me this error ..

```
    java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 10
at pkg12.NewApplet.init(NewApplet.java:69)
at sun.applet.AppletPanel.run(AppletPanel.java:435)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

and I don't know why so I can't fix it ..

here's my code

```
 package pkg12;

 import java.applet.Applet;
 import java.awt.Graphics;
 import java.awt.Image;
 import java.util.Random;

public class NewApplet extends Applet
{

Image card1;
Image card2;
Image card3;
Image card4;
Image card5;
Image card6;
Image card7;
Image card8;
Image card9;
Image card10;

public void init()
{
    Random random = new Random();
    String cards[][] = {{"c1.gif", "c2.gif", "c3.gif", "c4.gif",
   "c5.gif", "c6.gif", "c7.gif", "c8.gif", "c9.gif", 
   "c10.gif", "cj.gif", "ck.gif", "cq.gif"},
  {"s1.gif", "s2.gif", "s3.gif", "s4.gif",
   "s5.gif", "s6.gif", "s7.gif", "s8.gif",
   "s9.gif", "s10.gif", "sj.gif", "sk.gif",
   "sq.gif"}, {"d1.gif", "d2.gif", "d3.gif",
   "d4.gif", "d5.gif", "d6.gif", "d7.gif",
   "d8.gif", "d9.gif", "d10.gif", "dj.gif",
   "dk.gif", "dq.gif"}, {"h1.gif", "h2.gif",
   "h3.gif", "h4.gif", "h5.gif", "h6.gif",
   "h7.gif", "h8.gif", "h9.gif", "h10.gif",
   "hj.gif", "hk.gif", "hq.gif"}};

    int selectedCard[] = new int[10];
    int selectedSuit[] = new int[10];
    int suit = random.nextInt(4);
    int card = random.nextInt(13);
    boolean newCard = false;

    for(int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
    {
        while(newCard = false)
        {
            newCard = true;
            suit = random.nextInt(4);
            card = random.nextInt(13);

            for(int y = 0; y < x; y++)
            {
                if(selectedCard[y] == card && selectedSuit[y] == suit)
                {
                    newCard = false;
                }
            }
        }

        selectedCard[x] = card;
        selectedSuit[x] = suit;
    }
    card10 = getImage(getDocumentBase(), cards[selectedSuit[10]][selectedCard[11]]);

    card1 = getImage(getDocumentBase(), cards[selectedSuit[1]][selectedCard[1]]);
    card2 = getImage(getDocumentBase(), cards[selectedSuit[2]][selectedCard[2]]);
    card3 = getImage(getDocumentBase(), cards[selectedSuit[3]][selectedCard[3]]);
    card4 = getImage(getDocumentBase(), cards[selectedSuit[4]][selectedCard[4]]);
    card5 = getImage(getDocumentBase(), cards[selectedSuit[5]][selectedCard[5]]);
    card6 = getImage(getDocumentBase(), cards[selectedSuit[6]][selectedCard[6]]);
    card7 = getImage(getDocumentBase(), cards[selectedSuit[7]][selectedCard[7]]);
    card8 = getImage(getDocumentBase(), cards[selectedSuit[8]][selectedCard[8]]);
    card9 = getImage(getDocumentBase(), cards[selectedSuit[9]][selectedCard[9]]);
   card10 = getImage(getDocumentBase(), cards[selectedSuit[10]][selectedCard[10]]);
}

public void paint(Graphics g)
{
    g.drawImage(card1, 30, 30, this);
    g.drawImage(card2, 30, 150, this);
    g.drawImage(card3, 120, 30, this);
    g.drawImage(card4, 120, 150, this);
    g.drawImage(card5, 210, 30, this);
    g.drawImage(card6, 210, 150, this);
    g.drawImage(card7, 300, 30, this);
    g.drawImage(card8, 300, 150, this);
    g.drawImage(card9, 390, 30, this);
    g.drawImage(card10, 390, 150, this);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `selectedSuit` and `selectedCard` are `new int[10]`

```
card10 = getImage(getDocumentBase(), cards[selectedSuit[10]][selectedCard[11]]);
```

Comment: now it showa these error messages : java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 11
 at Assignment_12.init(Assignment_12.java:81)
 at sun.applet.AppletPanel.run(AppletPanel.java:435)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

Answer (score 0):

You array size is 10 soo you can only get up to index 9 since arrays are starting from 0

Please change the following

```
 card1 = getImage(getDocumentBase(), cards[selectedSuit[0]][selectedCard[0]]);


card10 = getImage(getDocumentBase(), cards[selectedSuit[9]][selectedCard[9]]);
```